# Nav drop down z-index / positioning issue

Tags: css

My problem is the drop down menu is not on top of the elements positioned below it. If I remove the relative positioning of the .header, the drop down is on top, but I need that rule to get the higher zindex to set the .header above the slider.

Here is a link:
http://thomasgrauer.com/inbound/

Comment: Have you tried removing `overflow: auto;` from your `<header>`?

Answer (score -1):

You need to remove **"overflow: auto"** from header. **Line 148** in your **main.css** file.

Comment: Dang. Looks like I just got snipped!

Comment: We just posted at the same time, no big deal, bro. Take it easy.

Answer (score -1):

Here's my answer from the comments.

Have you tried removing `overflow: auto;` from your `<header>`?